# Finding parameter $a$, with which function $f(x) = ax +\sin^2(x)$ value decreases in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

I've found the derivative:
 $f'(x) = a + \sin(2x)$
But I have no clue what the next step is.

Comment: presumably you want the derivative to always be negative (or at least never positive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be $$f'(x)\le 0$$ this means $$a+\sin(2x)\le 0$$